# Centering a line of numbers below a main line

Tags: java, math, centering

I have a set of numbers 1-9.  I have a variable set of numbers (example 1-3, 1-4, or 1-7, etc).  I need to center the second set of numbers (the variable) to the first set. If the second set of numbers is even, then move the second set closer to one.

Example:

> 123456789
>
> 000123000

In the example above 4 correlates to 1, 5 correlates to 2, and 6 correlates to 3.

or

> 123456789
>
> 001234000

or

> 123456789
>
> 012345670

I am having a difficult time breaking the problem down so that I can center the second line of text off of the first line. The "0" is not important and added to the example to show space differences. I think this is basic math but I am missing something. Thanks for your help!

Edit #1:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    private static final int maxNumberOfItems = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfItems = 6; // Any number between 1 and 9.
        int difference = maxNumberOfItems - numberOfItems;
        int dividedDifference;
        boolean isEven = (numberOfItems % 2) == 0;

        if (isEven) {
            dividedDifference = (difference - 1) / 2;
        } else {
            dividedDifference = difference / 2;
        }

        printAnswer(numberOfItems, dividedDifference, isEven);
    }

    private static void printAnswer(int numberOfItems, int dividedDifference, boolean isEven) {
        //TODO: Print answer here to console.

        // Desired output:
        // 123456789 (represents maxNumberOfItems)
        // --1234--- (represents numberOfItems)

        // Pseudo logic.
        // Figure out if the var numberOfItems is odd or even.
        // If its odd, subtract the numberOfItems from the maxNumberOfItems.
        // Take that number and divide by two. That gives the amount of spaces to skip on each side.
        // If the number is even, subtract one and divide by two. Get the number of spaces on each side
        // and add one back to the right side.
    }
}
```

EDIT #2:

@Mbo asked me to elaborate and explain the "real problem." So here goes.  In a 3D world I have a group of pedestals that will spawn in a quarter circle based on the number of items to show. The pedestal locations are at fixed XYZ coordinates. These coordinates will never change. The locations are shown in the picture below. There can only ever be a max of 9 pedestals. The pedestals we want to show are based on the number of "items" (our changing variable) that we want to show. Ideally we always want to show them in the middle. If the number is even, then we want to show the pedestals in the middle but closer to 1 than 9. The numbering for this can be show in the top of the question in the block quotes.

> 123456789
>
> 001234000

Example Image:
[Representation of the quarter circle and pedestal locations.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqqS2.png)

It would be ideal to have a Map or HashMap that held the key item number and value pedestal location. As long as one pedestal is shown, then location 5 will always be used.

So given a map it may look something like this.

Example 1:

4 Items. 9 possible pedestal to be shown.

> Item 1 (key) to pedestal 3 location (value).
>
> Item 2 (key) to pedestal 4 location (value).
>
> Item 3 (key) to pedestal 5 location (value).
>
> Item 4 (key) to pedestal 6 location (value).

Note that the example above 4 does not divide evenly into 9, so the centering is offset and located closer to 1.

Example 2:

3 Items. 9 possible pedestal to be shown.

> Item 1 (key) to pedestal 4 location (value).
>
> Item 2 (key) to pedestal 5 location (value).
>
> Item 3 (key) to pedestal 6 location (value).

In this example 3 divides into 9 nicely so it can be perfectly centered.

This is the real problem.

Comment: What do you mean by Set. A Java `Set`? What does centering mean? Centering in a `String`, Array, ...? Please provide some Java code where your problem is located and what you do want to return.

Comment: maybe use substring and then pad the number - your question is not very clear and if you added some code showing what you tried, then I am sure you can get some more help

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Here is the pseudo code I have written. I am stuck at the printAnswer method. I just want to show the two line results in the console. One below the other like the examples above.

Comment: Your algorithm seems so complex for understanding because you need to optimize your code and exclude redundant calculations. For example, why do you use the variable "isEven".

Comment: What did you mean in the code:      if (isEven) {
            dividedDifference = (difference - 1) / 2;
        } else {
            dividedDifference = difference / 2;
        }

Comment: What is your real problem?

Comment: @MBo so the real problem.  Imagine a quarter circle of pedestals. The pedestals are located at a fixed location (X,Y,Z) in a 3D world and numbered 1-9. When a list of items is generated by code, say 4 as an example. The world needs to show the 4 middle most pedestals. The others will be hidden (given the 0's from above). Location 5 is the middle most pedestal. So if we only have one item, it will show 1 pedestal at location 5. I have tried to google the problem and I have tried several attempts to code a solution.

Comment: So... it is a problem of mutual centering of two strings depending on their length and ignoring contents? So what's wrong with  `shift=difference / 2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code to determine the value of `dividedDifference`.

`dividedDifference` represents the number of spaces to the right of the digits in the second row. This is true whether `numberOfItems` is even or odd, so `isEven` isn't necessary in your `printAnswer` method.

You've already performed most of the necessary logic before you invoke `printAnswer`, so most of the pseudocode in that method is redundant.

You can print your output to the console like this (the `isEven` parameter has been removed, so you'll want to remove that parameter where you're invoking the method too):

```
private static void printAnswer(int numberOfItems, int dividedDifference) {

    for(int i = 1; i <= maxNumberOfItems; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print(StringUtils.repeat(" ", dividedDifference));

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
    }

    System.out.print(StringUtils.repeat(" ", maxNumberOfItems - numberOfItems - dividedDifference));

}
```

Repository containing `StringUtils` can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have already done the work, it is not clear - what's wrong?

```
diff = maxNumberOfItems - numberOfItems;
//integer division gives desired result both for even and for odd diff
shift = (maxNumberOfItems - numberOfItems) / 2;

//mapping
location = key + shift;  

Number of items   shift     mapping
9                   0      (1->1, 9->9)
8                   0      (1->1, 8->8)
7                   1      (1->2, 7->8)
6                   1      (1->2, 6->7)
5                   2      (1->3, 5->7)
4                   2      (1->3, 4->6)
3                   3      (1->4, 3->6)
2                   3      (1->4, 2->5)
1                   4      (1->5)
```

Note that you can hard-code these values in array shifts[]

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to implement your algorithm is:

```
public class Main {

    private static final int maxNumberOfItems = 9;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfItems = 1531; // Any number between 1 and 9.
        int strLength = Integer.toString(numberOfItems).length(); // the length of the string presentation

        printAnswer(numberOfItems, strLength, maxNumberOfItems);
    }

    private static void printAnswer(int number, int start, int max) {
        String str = Integer.toString(number);
        for (int i = start; i < max; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {   // in this conditions we define from
                str += "0";     // which side we need to append "0"
            } else {
                str = "0" + str;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

The main idea of this implementation is appending needed quantity of "0" from two sides for existed number interpretation to the string.

**OUTPUT:**

```
001531000
```